# jQuery DataTables adding dynamic headers and table row's not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am having an issue with rendering my `jQuery DataTable` correctly. I am dynamically generating the `headers` for my table from a CSV Data source. From there I am just adding the corresponding table data from the CSV.

The issue is in where I am calling `.row.add([data.Data[i]]);`. If I include the `[]` brackets that surround my `data.Data[i]` object -- the table is rendered incorrectly. (see picture below)

[image]

Vs.

When I simply remove the `[]` the `headers` are correct but then the `data.Data` does not show - when inspecting the DOM. I find a `jQuery` error of `Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined`.

[image]

I have also included a picture from the DOM of the object that is getting passed back.
[image]

Question:

Is there something that I am missing in my code (below) that is preventing me from having the correct desired output of formatted table `headers` with dynamic data? I have also created a fiddle - which has the correct output but for some reason it is not working, please help [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zz9fpu2z/1/)

### JavaScript Code:

```
(function Launch() {
//console.log("Inside the GET Call: ");

$.get("/Home/CsvPath")
    .done(function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var csvFilePath = data.FullPath;
        GetCsvData(csvFilePath);
    });
}());


function GetCsvData(csvFilePath) {

//console.log("Inside the POST Call: ");

$.post("/Home/ReadCsv", { csvFilePath: csvFilePath })
    .done(function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);

        var formattedHeaders = [];
        $.each(data.Headers, function(e, f) {
            formattedHeaders.push({ "sTitle": data.Headers[e]});
        });

        var csvTable = $("#csvData-table")
            .DataTable({
                "stateSave": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "destroy": false,
                "paging": false,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "responsive": true,
                "columns": formattedHeaders
            });

        csvTable.clear();
        csvTable.draw();

        console.log(data.Data);
        console.log(data)

       // var csvData = data;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Headers.length; i++) {

            csvTable.row.add(
                data.Data[i]
            )
        }

        csvTable.draw();

    });
};
```

Comment: I believe you are looking something like this :  https://jsfiddle.net/zz9fpu2z/18/

Comment: @Nimmi, thank you for answering. However, that is not the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solved:

The issue was the fact that there was not enough data in my rows depending on the number of headers. Which was causing the error within the `DOM` - a simple edit and fixing the loop allowed me to achieve the correct result.

```
(function Launch() {
//console.log("Inside the GET Call: ");

$.get("/Home/CsvPath")
    .done(function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var csvFilePath = data.FullPath;
        GetCsvData(csvFilePath);
    });
}());


function GetCsvData(csvFilePath) {

//console.log("Inside the POST Call: ");

$.post("/Home/ReadCsv", { csvFilePath: csvFilePath })
    .done(function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);

        var formattedHeaders = [];
        $.each(data.Headers, function(e, f) {
            formattedHeaders.push({ "sTitle": data.Headers[e]});
        });

        var csvTable = $("#csvData-table")
            .DataTable({
                "stateSave": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "destroy": false,
                "paging": false,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "responsive": true,
                "columns": formattedHeaders
            });

        csvTable.clear();
        csvTable.draw();

        csvTable.rows.add(
            data.Data
        );

        csvTable.draw();

    });
};
```